# Trying to put an enum into a select form helper class in rails 5

Tags: ruby, forms, select, enums, ruby-on-rails-5

I have

```
<%= f.select(:status, [["active", 0], ["inactive", 1], ['cancelled', 2]]) %>
```

And originally

```
<%= f.select(:status, collection: Subscription::STATUSES) %>
```

But both don't work.

Heres subscription.rb

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :plan

  STATUSES = {active: 0, inactive: 1, cancelled: 2}
  enum status: STATUSES
end
```

Every time I try like this I get:

```
private method `select' called for nil:NilClass
```

And every time I try following guides I get that message for alternatively failing syntax.

It's a headscratcher i'll leave until morning.

You may want to see

```
<%= form_tag subscription_path, id: "subscription-form" do |f| %>
```

And therefore:

```
match "plans/subscriptions" => "subscriptions#new", as: "subscription", via: [:get, :post]
```

Comment: For enum `Subscription.statuses`

Comment: Seems like you mixed out `form_tag` with `form_for`. The `form_tag` method you are using does not yield a FormBuilder to the block. Therefore, there is no `f` when using `from_tag`. Only `form_for` (which has a different signature) allows using `f` within the block.

Comment: @spickermann exactly right, thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get value in select from `enum => status` try this

```
= f.select :status, Subscription.statuses.keys.map { |w| [w.humanize, w] }
```

Or by constant `STATUS`

```
= f.select :status, Subscription::STATUSES
```

**Edit**

As @spickermann comment for `form_tag` you can use like this

```
<%= select_tag :status, options_for_select(Subscription.statuses.map {w| [w.humanize, w]}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**What you want in Rails 7 is this:**

```
<%= form.select :status, Subscription.statuses.keys %>
```

Subscription.statuses is set automatically and is not needed as constant via:

```
enum status: {"active"=>0, "inactive"=>1, "cancelled"=>2}
```